# Assign null value to data row

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to write one line IF condition when assign value to property.
I've tried these syntax in VB.NET, `type_of_documents` is nullable integer:

```
1)   vehicle.type_of_documents = If(vehicle.Istype_of_documentsNull, SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null, vehicle.type_of_documents)
2)   vehicle.type_of_documents = If(vehicle.Istype_of_documentsNull, DBNull.Value, vehicle.type_of_documents)
3)   vehicle.type_of_documents = If(vehicle.Istype_of_documentsNull, Nothing, vehicle.type_of_documents)
```

Well, I am a little pushy to do this in one line. Somehow, all these syntax have failed to assign null value to my database. Syntax 1 & 2 have thrown cast integer exception. Syntax 3 is no error but no change/update value in database (same as previous).

Can anyone show me better syntax? Since I am really not into VB.NET.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The conditions in the If: first parameter like in a "normal" If. Second parameter if true, third parameter if false: `vehicle.type_of_documents = If(vehicle.type_of_documents Is Nothing, SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null, vehicle.type_of_documents)`

Comment: yes, but I got an error with your syntax condition @muffi

Comment: Show us the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `If` operator is basically generic, i.e. the type it returns is inferred from the type of the second and third arguments. That means that those two arguments have to be the same type or one must assignable from the type of the other.  A simple cast is all you need:

```
vehicle.type_of_documents = If(vehicle.Istype_of_documentsNull,
                               CObj(DBNull.Value),
                               vehicle.type_of_documents)
```

Now that the first argument is specified to be type `Object`, the two arguments share a type.

Answer (score 0):

Return type of `If` method will be inferred from result parameters (as @jmcilhinney already answered).
In 1 and 2 samples you get cast exception because `Integer` cannot be casted to `SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null` and `DbNull.Value` types.
Third sample compile because `Nothing` can be introduced as `Integer`, it simply default value of `Integer` which equals `0`.

If you want return `DbNull.Value` in case when `type_of_documents` has no value - you need cast results in their common type, which is `Object`.

Instead of `If` method you can create extension method which return common type(object) required by SqlParameters

```
Public Module Extensions
    <Extension>
    Public Function GetValueOrDbNull(this As Integer?) As Object
        If this.HasValue Then Return this
        Return DBNull.Value
    End Function
End Module
```

And use it

```
Dim sqlValue = vehicle.type_of_documents.GetValueOrDbNull()
```